# AS3 - how to 'cut out' a section of Sprite that has a filter?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, filter

I draw on a Sprite on using 'drawPath'.

I then apply a filter to this Sprite using :

```
var myBlur:BlurFilter = new BlurFilter();
myBlur.blurX = 10;
myBlur.blurY = 10;
_alphaMask.filters = [myBlur];
```

I then need to 'cut' out a section of the sprite and use it as a mask on a different sprite.

The problem is - when I cut out the Sprite - I need the cut 'edges' to not be blurred,

but the 'BlurFilter' is applied on the 'cut' Sprite, so the edges are blurred.

Here is the [problem in pictures](http://s11.postimage.org/820by8y29/Prblm_Mask2.png) :

[problem in pictures http://s11.postimage.org/820by8y29/Prblm_Mask2.png](http://s11.postimage.org/820by8y29/Prblm_Mask2.png)

I thought of a way to solve it that has 2 problems:

Draw the BitmapData from the Sprite with the filter on to a new Sprite,
and then use 'scrollRect' on the new Sprite.

There are 2 problems with this approach:

1. Perfomance hit
2. Can't get it to work ...

Can someone tell me how I can solve this need without copying the bitmap data ??

**UPDATE**

Here is the code snippet I use:

```
private var _alphaMask:Sprite;

private createMask():void
{
    _alphaMask = new Sprite();
    _alphaMask.visible = true;

    // Clear the mask
    _alphaMask.graphics.clear();

    // Create the mask vertices (the 'drawPath' coordinates)
    var maskPoints:Vector.<Number> = new Vector.<Number>(5);
    maskPoints.push(100);   maskPoints.push(100);
    maskPoints.push(200);   maskPoints.push(200);
    maskPoints.push(230);   maskPoints.push(310);
    maskPoints.push(140);   maskPoints.push(170);
    maskPoints.push(130);   maskPoints.push(190);

    // Create the 'drawPath' commands
    var commands:Vector.<int> = new Vector.<int>(commandLen);
    commands.push(1);
    commands.push(2);
    commands.push(2);
    commands.push(2);
    commands.push(2);

    // Draw the vertices on the mask
    _alphaMask.graphics.beginFill(0x0000FF);
    _alphaMask.graphics.drawPath(commands, clonedMaskPoints);
    _alphaMask.graphics.endFill();

        // Add the Blur filter to the mask
    var myBlur:BlurFilter   = new BlurFilter();
    myBlur.blurX            = myBlur.blurY = 10;
    _alphaMask.filters      = [myBlur];



    // Now I need to 'Cut Out' a section of the mask (and use it for something else...)
    // This section cuts out the part of the mask I need, but it 'reapplies' the blur filter on the entire cut mask
    var scrollRect_x:Number         = 100;
    var scrollRect_y:Number         = 100;
    var scrollRect_width:Number     = 300;
    var scrollRect_height:Number    = 200
    _alphaMask.scrollRect = new Rectangle(scrollRect_x, scrollRect_y, scrollRect_width, scrollRect_height);
}
```

and this is what I tried to work-around the problem (without success):

```
var alphaBitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(_alphaMask.width, _alphaMask.height);
alphaBitmapData.draw(_alphaMask);
_alphaMask.graphics.clear();
_alphaMask.graphics.beginBitmapFill(alphaBitmapData);
_alphaMask.graphics.endFill();
```

Comment: You're already trying to do this by copying the bitmap data, so I'm not sure why you want the solution not to do that. Post your code, and it will be easier to show you what you can change than whip up all new code (hence take less time on the part of someone answering).

Comment: And what is the result of this code? You say you can't get it to work, but does it do anything at all?

Comment: the _alphaMask is empty. nothing shown in it.

Comment: If you just create a Bitmap from your alphaBitmapData and add that to the stage, what do you see?

Comment: I would like to just 'slice' a piece of my mask onto a new Sprite object. How can this be done ? Do I need to copy it to a bitmap object and then use this bitmap object to create a new Sprite object ? or can I directly slice a section from my 'Sprite' to a new 'Sprite' ?

Comment: Can you please help me by posting a code snippet to help me figure things out ?

Comment: I am trying to help you with the steps I would use when trying to do a similar task if it wasn't working. It's hard to tell what is wrong without having full access to all your objects. Here is a working example that is manipulating bitmap objects in a way similar to what you want to do http://flexdiary.blogspot.com/2012/06/endless-scrolling-bathroom.html .

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19047/discussion-between-john-miner-and-amy-blankenship)